# you are using ARC welder on a non-chrome os device. platform specific bugs exist.

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, google-chrome-arc

my chrome version is 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit)
arc welder is 46.5021.478.18.
there is a issue :  you are using ARC welder on a non-chrome os device.
platform specific bugs exist.

how to solve it ?  i have installed the newest chrome . but the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same message too, but it does not block you from using ARC Welder, after you dismiss this message, you can find ARC Welder in your Chrome App List, click it to run it. It ran well on my Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a warning message. It can be ignored.
The arc welder converts successfully the apk to zip file. (some issues with publishing on Chrome web store still exists, see my post here [Chrome app store porting from Android app using arc welder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36170936/chrome-app-store-migration-from-android-app-using-arc-welder))
Also the test of the app works as expected.